# Flag is declined; but no other option is applicable

Tags: discussion

[Dynamics CRM 365 - How to change System Entity Icon on the SiteMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633100/dynamics-crm-365-how-to-change-system-entity-icon-on-the-sitemap)

I have flagged this as below:

> Looks like the user posted the question & answered himself within span of minutes (but needs minimum a couple of hours efforts, he mentioned he got help from Lead designer too). hopefully this should be a blog post but not a SO content – Arun Vinoth 2 hours ago

Result:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Query:
I doubt thats a legitimate problem looking for answer. He just documented a blog by splitting into QA in FAQ style. Just for reputation?

Comment: It's not a problem at all to answer your own question, even if you answer it in a span of minutes.

Comment: I think the implication in the answer was that to edit the graphics file you might need someone that can edit it correctly and that it might take time to do so. Apart from needing a little bit of fluff removed from the answer - it looks like a useful Q&A for someone that might be wondering the same and willing to use a workaround if that's the only way possible. That the Q and the A are from the same person is not a problem.

Comment: i agree with your point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> Can I answer my own question?
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

So the flag was declined because it is not against the rules to self-answer.

Of course if a self-answered question is worthy of a flag, then it should be flagged as such, but not *just* because it is self-answered.